# How to fix "groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute" issue?

Tags: groovy, ubuntu-16.04

http://groovy-lang.org/install.html

I have tried to install groovy using (SDKMAN type) above link in ubuntu 16.04 but when i'm trying to verify the installed groovy version. `groovy -version`

I'm getting below error

`groovy: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly, can not execute:`

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Do you have installed a jdk?  E.g. using SDKMAN or from the OS?

Comment: Yes I have installed jdk

Comment: Search the web for setting JAVA_HOME